# payment subscriptions

Tags: civicontribute

I have to set CiviCRM to collect subscriptions for next year.

1. The membership fee is 190,00(childs) and € 225.00(adults).
2. if a child has a brother, the brother has a discount of 5%
3. Who pays can divide the payment: 90.00 € by 01/07/2015 and the remaining by 12/01/2015
4. Who pays for it all at once has a discount of 5%.

I can set these payments CiviCRM? How?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several parts to your question, so I'll try to address them separately.

- Part 1 you can handle with [price sets](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Membership+Price+Sets).
- Part 2 can be handled with the [CiviDiscount](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount) extension, if the requirement is that both children are registered at once.  If they can be registered separately, you'll need a hook that checks for the relationship.
- Part 3 is the tricky part - what you're looking for is called "front-end partial payments".  This has been written as [custom code](https://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/frontend-partial-payments-development-framework) by Back Office Thinking - and there's a group of developers gathering funding to [build something like this in core](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-14538).  However, there's no way to do this today without custom code.
- Part 4 you can also handle with a price set.